# Why are default values for patience in EarlyStopping and ReduceLROnPlateau so different?

Tags: python, keras

There is a patience parameter both in [EarlyStopping](https://keras.io/api/callbacks/early_stopping/) and [ReduceLROnPlateau](https://keras.io/api/callbacks/reduce_lr_on_plateau/) in Keras. However, the patience parameter for EarlyStopping is 0 meanwhile 10 for ReduceLROnPlateau. Assuming they both monitor val_loss by default, how ReduceLROnPlateau would work if it never has a chance to update itself because of the high patience number?

Then, by logic, patience for EarlyStopping should always be greater than ReduceLROnPlateau, right?

Answer (score 0):

A simplified implementation is below:

```py
class ReduceLROnPlateau:
    def on_epoch_end(self):
        if current < self.best - self.min_delta:
            self.best = current
            self.wait = 0
            return

        self.wait += 1

        if self.wait >= self.patience:
            self.wait = 0
            self.drop_lr()
```

Notice the `min_delta`. It controls whether or not we *detect* a new best value. Small improvements are not detected -- they are ignored. If we beat the previously *detected* best (which is *not* necessarily the actual best!), then we reset the `wait` counter.

Same idea with `EarlyStopping`.

However, note the different choices:

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `ReduceLROnPlateau` | patience=10 | min_delta=0.0001 |
| `EarlyStopping` | patience=0 | min_delta=0 |

So... `EarlyStopping` is much more relaxed about what it considers a change. If the loss decreases *very* smoothly **but monotonically**, we may still see an LR drop when it goes below `min_delta` for 10 epochs. In practice, loss is not that smooth, and if it stops being monotonically decreasing, `EarlyStopping` will terminate the training.

That's why you should probably increase its patience to, e.g. `patience=11`. See also: PyTorch's `ReduceLROnPlateau` defaults. And PyTorch also does relative delta, rather than absolute delta...

---

NOTE: PyTorch uses entirely different parameter values and algorithm, so this explanation is only for Keras.